# Subaru Impreza Turbo 2000 Stuttering acceleration and clunk

Tags: noise, subaru, acceleration, turbocharger, impreza

The car is a manual and right hand drive. Pulling away or moving off at low rpm, there is a small stutter. It is always when a little throttle is applied.
But much more noticeable is a massive stuttering when under 60% - 80% throttle and the turbo has kicked in with what seams like clunking coming from the turbo or airbox juddering power loss but still accelerates. Car runs fine maintaining speed or engine braking.

With clutch down non of these issues can be heard.
This issue seams to have got worse as I have been driving it.
I was aware that the front right differential needs changing as there has been a whining sound on right hand corners for a while. Also the clutch is in need of a change.

Please let me know if you know what the issue is.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Worn engine/transmission mounts? Check the engine for unusual movement when someone else is revving it. The Impreza has two engine mounts - one on each head, and one the transmission. They do go bad on older cars.

Also change the front right driveshaft. Not a big job - about two/three hours for a beginner, 30 minutes for a mechanic. Maybe do both while you're in there; they're the same age and mileage.

Comment: That could well be it. I noticed a long time ago that when I rev the engine in neutral, the gear stick moves. Will test later today. Thanks!

Comment: There is a bit of engine movement when throttle is applied. But no more than about half and inch. Sounds like there is a misfire. A pop from the airbox or turbo when throttle is applied. Its a load pop and but not a dump valve sound.